# how to fit this delayed decayed oscillatory system response(Padé and Prony approximant seem not work very well)

Tags: real-analysis

[image: decayed oscillatory system response]
I have this system response as shown in the figure. it's oscillatory and decayed. I have tried Padé and Prony approximation but they seem not work very well. It seems to me that Prony approximation not working for delayed signal. and Padé approximation not working for the oscillatory signal.

Comment: Did you try Fourier-analysis ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici This is for you, Claude

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I try to catch the system's frequency response, but Fourier analysis needs the signal long enough to achieve the frequency resolution.

Comment: what is your sample rate? It looks as if the nyquist frequency is well above the significant characteristic frequencies of the signal, so there should be no problem using Fourier. This also looks too clean to be a measured signal. What is generating it?

Comment: Correct. It's a response by numerical simulation(and it's truncated, I only have this). Sample rate is not the problem(you can see it is very smooth), the problem is the total time of the signal is too short to achieve good frequency resolution with Fourier transform. So I am trying Prony's method...but not so successful so far--most probably my knowledge is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

The plot looks to me like a sinusoidal mixture rather than a pure decay. Try computing the FFT. My guess is there will be a handful of frequencies which dominate the spectrum. Then try fitting the oscillatory response to a truncated Fourier model of the form
$$
f(t) = \sum_{\omega_i}\{a(\omega_i)\sin(\omega_i t) + b(\omega_i)\cos(\omega_i t)\},
$$ 
where the $\omega_i$ are the dominant frequencies observed in the FFT. Since the basis is fixed you can estimate coefficients using a least squares fit.